# Why does `"abc"[10:11]` not produce an index error but `"abc"[10]` does?

Tags: python, string, indexing

When printing `"abc"[10]`, it returns `IndexError` as expected, but when changing the index to `[10:11]`, it just returns `""`.

What makes the two index statements different?

Comment: The 2nd one is slicing, not indexing- that just how it works

Comment: Ah right, I didn't manage to find that link, thank you.